# Help with Apache Redirect 301

Tags: apache-2.2, 301-redirect

I recently moved my blog on to my company website and did a 301 redirect for all the content of my blog. However I want to redirect my the base url (www.oldblog.com) of my old blog to my new company blog (www.newblog.com/category/blog)

Currently all the content is mapped 1 to 1 using this htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

How do I map only the root to a different place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See mod_alias [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive.